# How to pass row data to a child component created into a format function

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I have a react-bootstrap table with column defined like this:

```
  const columns = [
    ...
    {
      dataField: "d",
      text: "Actions",
      formatter: actionFormatter,
      headerAlign: "center",
    },
  ];
```

The formatter function looks like this:

```
  const actionFormatter = (cell, row) => {
    return (
      <div className="action-cell text-center">
        <Tooltip title="View file">
          <span className="svg-icon svg-icon-xl" onClick={setSelectRow}>
            <SVG
              src={toAbsoluteUrl("/media/svg/icons/General/Binocular.svg")}
            />
          </span>
        </Tooltip>

        <Tooltip title="Download file">
          <span className="svg-icon svg-icon-xl">
            {/* Rename file on download */}
            <SVG
              src={toAbsoluteUrl("/media/svg/icons/Files/Download.svg")}
              onClick={setSelectRow}
            />
          </span>
        </Tooltip>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

The first part is used to show some content in an other component. I needed to get data to the parent component. **But the problem is that the formatter is created once and only once at the component creation, it has no idea about any event or changes happening to row**. I already struggled to do this but finished by getting it done  by doing something like this:

```
  const rowEvents = {
    onClick: (e, row, rowIndex) => {
      setSelectedRow(row);
      setSelectedRowIsReady(true);
    },
  };
```

So, this method allow me to get the selected row by a click event on the row,

then,

```
  const setSelectRow = useCallback(() => {
    if (selectedRowIsReady) {
      props.onSelectSetting(selectedRow);
    }
  }, [props, selectedRow, selectedRowIsReady]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectRow();
  }, [setSelectRow]);
```

the setSelectRow function allow me to send my row to the parent components, I had to put it in a useEffect hook because the onClick function was called before the rowEvents.

So... not very clean but at least working as expected.

Now, what I want do to is replace my formatter to look like this:

```
  <div className="action-cell text-center">
    <Tooltip title="View file">
      <span className="svg-icon svg-icon-xl" onClick={setSelectRow}>
        <SVG
          src={toAbsoluteUrl("/media/svg/icons/General/Binocular.svg")}
        />
      </span>
    </Tooltip>
    <SystemFileDownload row={selectedRow} />
  </div>
```

However I do not know how to get my row into my child component because, when onClick is called, the state isn't already set. I thought about setting my selected row into my redux store but it feels kind of overkill for what I am trying to achieve.
How could I simply pass my current row to my child component ?

I tried to add my state to formatExtraData like this:

```
{
  dataField: "d",
  text: "Actions",
  formatter: actionFormatter,
  headerAlign: "center",
  formatExtraData: selectedRow,
},
```

and then use selectedRow onto my props, but my child component got the row that was click on the previous click and not on the current click.

So I tried to set my row into my redux. Obviously I got the same problem, the onclick function is triggered before the rowEvents function.

So I added this to my child component:

```
  useEffect(
    (
      downloadFileHandler = () => {
        console.log("Download");
        // Will get the data from the API
        const fake_data = '{"hello": "no"}';
        console.log(selectedConf);
        console.log(systemName);
        const fileName = ``;
      }
    ) => {
      if (firstUpdate.current) {
        firstUpdate.current = false;
        return;
      }
      downloadFileHandler();
    },
    [selectedConf]
  );
```

Where I get selectedConf from my redux store, and it is set on click on a row.
But then, when I click on my download button, the useEffect hook get triggered as many time as my child component exists on the page, even if it's not part of the BootstrapTable I am working on, so not good, I do not know how to avoid this.

I feel like I am missing something obvious because my use case is like very common and simple and I have to use hooks and redux to achieve it instead of a simple props and it isn't even working.